# How to plot audio waveform in PyQtGraph

Tags: python, matplotlib, audio, plot, pyqtgraph

I am working on my thesis project that needs to manipulate audio waveform. And I am really having a trouble plotting my audio waveform with PyQtGraph and could not find any solution.

I have tried plotting it with matplotlib and works really fine.

Here is a code by plotting with matplotlib embedded on a tkinter window (Won't post the complete code for tkinter canvas embedding because I don't think it's not the focus of my problem):

```
 def waveform(self, audio):
    self.waveFile = wave.open(audio, 'rb')  # reading wave file
    format = p.get_format_from_width(self.waveFile.getsampwidth())
    channel = self.waveFile.getnchannels()
    rate = self.waveFile.getframerate()
    self.frame = self.waveFile.getnframes()
    self.stream = p.open(format=format,  # DATA needed for streaming
                         channels=channel,
                         rate=rate,
                         output=True)

    durationF = self.frame / float(rate)
    plt.title('Audio Waveform')
    self.data_int = self.waveFile.readframes(self.frame)
    self.data_plot = np.fromstring(self.data_int, dtype=np.short)
    self.data_plot.shape = -1, 2
    self.data_plot = self.data_plot.T
    self.time = np.arange(0, self.frame) * (1.0 / rate)
    self.fig = Figure(figsize=(30, 6), dpi=30)
    self.fig.set_size_inches(34, 5.3)
    self.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.09, right=1.05, top=1.00, wspace=0, hspace=0)
    self.fig.tight_layout()
    self.xticks = np.arange(0, self.timeDuration, 15)
    self.wavePlot = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.wavePlot.set_xticks(self.xticks)
    if (channel == 1):
        print 'Just mono files only'
        self.wavePlot.plot(self.time, self.data_plot[0])

    elif (channel == 2):
        print 'Just stereo files only'
        self.wavePlot.plot(self.time, self.data_plot[1], c="b")

    self.wavePlot.tick_params(axis='both', which="major", labelsize=20)
    self.wavePlot.tick_params(axis='both', which="minor", labelsize=30)

    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.waveFrame)
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

And when I discovered PyQtGraph, I switched to it for more interactive and fast plotting. 
Now when I do this with almost exactly the same thing in PyQt/PyQtGraph, errors came up and I couldn't plot it anymore.

Here is my code for plotting with PyQtGraph in PyQT4:

```
 def waveform(self, audio):
    self.waveFile = wave.open(audio,'rb')
    self.format = p.get_format_from_width(self.waveFile.getsampwidth())
    channel = self.waveFile.getnchannels()
    self.rate = self.waveFile.getframerate()
    self.frame = self.waveFile.getnframes()
    self.stream = p.open(format=self.format,  # DATA needed for streaming
                         channels=channel,
                         rate=self.rate,
                         output=True)

    durationF = self.frame / float(self.rate)

    #Setting up waveform plot
    self.data_int = self.waveFile.readframes(self.frame)
    self.data_plot = np.fromstring(self.data_int, 'Int16')
    self.time = np.arange(0, self.frame) * (1.0 / self.rate)

     self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title='Spectrum Analyzer')
    self.win.setWindowTitle('Spectrum Analyzer')
    self.win.setGeometry(5, 115, 1910, 1070)

    wf_xlabels = [(0, '0'), (2048, '2048'), (4096, '4096')]
    wf_xaxis = pg.AxisItem(orientation='bottom')
    wf_xaxis.setTicks([wf_xlabels])

    wf_ylabels = [(0, '0'), (127, '128'), (255, '255')]
    wf_yaxis = pg.AxisItem(orientation='left')
    wf_yaxis.setTicks([wf_ylabels])

    self.waveform = self.win.addPlot(
        title='WAVEFORM', row=1, col=1, axisItems={'bottom': wf_xaxis, 
              'left': wf_yaxis},
              )
    self.waveform.plot(pen='c', width=3)
    self.waveform.setYRange(0,255, padding=0)
    self.waveform.setXRange(0,2 * self.chunk, padding = 0.005)
    self.waveform.plot(self.time, self.data_plot)
```

When I run the above code, an error that says ---in updateData
raise Exception("X and Y arrays must be the same shape--got %s and %s." % (self.xData.shape, self.yData.shape))
Exception: X and Y arrays must be the same shape--got (1535696L,) and (767848L,).

I tried different plotting ways and I haven't come up to any solution to plot it. I wonder why matplotlib code works fine with it and PyQtGraph doesn't?
Any response would be a BIG help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X and Y must have the same length. In your error message one is twice as long as the other.

In your MatPlotLib code example is some code that seems reshape the `self.data_plot` into two rows.

```
self.data_plot.shape = -1, 2
self.data_plot = self.data_plot.T
```

This functionality is missing in the PyQtGraph code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I edited and inserted that lines but I get the same error but different array shape error in dataType
 ------ raise Exception('array shape must be (N,) or (N,2); got %s instead' % str(obj.shape))
Exception: array shape must be (N,) or (N,2); got (2L, 383924L) instead.


Unfortunately maybe plotting in PyQtGraph is different in matplotlib? I'm really new to plotting and have to discover this for my project but I'm stuck.

Comment: There might be differences between Matplotlib and PyQtGraph but in this case the difference are between your examples. The `data_plot` array has two rows because it contains data of two channels. In your Matplotlib code you select the first row by putting `self.data_plot[0]` in the plot command. In your PyQtGraph plot you just pass the entire array with `self.waveform.plot(self.time, self.data_plot)`. Change this to `self.waveform.plot(self.time, self.data_plot[0])` to plot the first channel. BTW during debugging it helps to print the shape of the arrays so that you can see if they are correct

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! But one more thing, it finally plots but the graph was so big. I will link the image here: https://imgur.com/a/sbTzkY8 ----As you can see the x label (time) is accurate with 0 to 8 seconds of the audio file but the plotting is so huge.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you think I have sufficiently answered then please mark the question as *accepted* by clicking on the check mark. I am not sure what you mean by "the graph is so big". Is the window too large? Is it the X-axis range too large? Since this is an unrelated problem I recommend that you make a new post and explain it in some more detail. This also ensures that other people will see your new question.

Comment: Checked. Sorry, I'm quite new in stackoverflow. If you could view the link it has the screenshot of the graph on it and what I meant by big, X range are what I need but the Y isn't. I know pyqtgraph can zoom in zoom out the graph but the initial display is huge. Thanks again, I'll post a new topic but I will still look forward to your reply since you helped me now and then. Thank you.